# how should I collect data from a child component when I use react hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

"I have a modal component containing a complex form. To simplify the form handling, I created a separate child component. However, I'm encountering an issue where I can't obtain the correct data from the child component.

The child component consists of a checkbox and an input field. My goal is to create an object like this when the checkbox is true:

```
[{"goalId":1,"value":"-3"}]
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I check the checkbox, the state gets updated immediately and doesn't wait for input from the user. I'm seeking guidance on best practices to resolve this issue.

here is the child component :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useGetGoalsAllQuery } from "@/infrastructure/slice/goal.slice";
import { Checkbox, FormControlLabel } from "@mui/material";
import Loading from "@/components/utils/loading.component";
import { InputController } from "@/components/utils/input/input-controller.component";

interface Props {
  control: any;
  onSelect: (goals: { id: number; weight: number }[]) => void;
  getValues: any
}

const MacroGoalsExpectations: React.FC<Props> = ({ control, onSelect, getValues }) => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetGoalsAllQuery();
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState<number[]>([]);

  console.log("isSelected", isSelected)


  const handleChange = (e: any, goalId: number) => {
    const goalChecked = e.target.checked;

    if (goalChecked) {
      if (!isSelected.includes(goalId)) {
        setIsSelected((prev) => [...prev, goalId]);
      }
    } else {
      setIsSelected(() => isSelected.filter((i) => i !== goalId));
    }

    const selectedGoalsWithWeights = data
      .filter((goal: any) => isSelected.includes(goal.id))
      .map((goal: any) => ({
        id: goal.id,
        weight: getValues(`weight${goal.id}`), 
      }));

      console.log("selectedGoalsWithWeights", selectedGoalsWithWeights)

    onSelect(selectedGoalsWithWeights);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <form>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label htmlFor="indicators" aria-required className="m-1 block text-sm">
              <span>اهداف کلان مرتبط با انتظار</span>
              <span className="text-red-600 mr-1">*</span>
            </label>
            <div className="border rounded border-slate-300">
              {data.map((goal: any) => (
                <div className="flex items-center p-2 w-1/2 justify-between" key={goal.id}>
                  <FormControlLabel
                    classes={{ label: "text-xs" }}
                    control={<Checkbox sx={{ padding: 0, marginLeft: 1 }} />}
                    label={goal.title}
                    value={goal.id}
                    onClick={(e) => handleChange(e, goal.id)}
                  />
                  <InputController
                    control={control}
                    name={`weight${goal.id}`}
                    type="number"
                    min={-5}
                    max={5}
                    formClassName="w-16 m-0"
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MacroGoalsExpectations;
```

and this is the parent :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { InputController } from "@/components/utils/input/input-controller.component";
import Modal from "@/components/utils/modal/modal.component";
import { SelectController } from "@/components/utils/select/select-controller.component";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Select, { MultiValue } from "react-select";
import ChooseIndicatorsModal from "./choose-indicators-modal.component";
import MacroGoalsExpectations from "./macro-goals-expectations.component";
import Button from "@/components/utils/button/button.component";
import { TextAreaController } from "@/components/utils/textarea/textarea-controller.component";

interface Props {
  onClose: () => void;
  id?: number;
}

interface Indicators {
  value: number;
  label: string;
  id?: number;
}

const groupOptions = [
  { value: 1, label: "کارکردی" },
  { value: 2, label: "غیر کارکردی" },
];

const StakeholdersExpectationsModal: React.FC<Props> = ({ onClose }) => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [indicators, setIndicators] = useState<MultiValue<Indicators>>([]);
  const [selectedGoals, setSelectedGoals] = useState<
    { id: number; weight: number }[]
  >([]);

  const { control, handleSubmit, getValues } = useForm();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpenModal(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenModal(false);
  };

  const handleChangeIndicators = (filteredList: any) => {
    setIndicators(
      filteredList.map((i: any) => ({ value: i.id, label: i.title }))
    );
  };

  const handleSelectedGoals = (goals: { id: number; weight: number }[]) => {
    setSelectedGoals(goals);
  };

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit((formBody) => {
    selectedGoals.map((e) => console.log("____" , e))
    console.log("formBody", formBody);
  });


  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen
      onClose={onClose}
      bodyClassName="w-[45rem]"
      title="اضافه کردن انتظارات ذینفعان"
    >
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <InputController
            control={control}
            name="title"
            label="عنوان انتظار"
            requiredInput
            rules={{ required: "لطفا عنوان انتظار را مشخص کنید." }}
            formClassName="w-3/5"
          />
          <SelectController
            control={control}
            name="group"
            options={groupOptions}
            label="گروه انتظار"
            requiredInput
            rules={{ required: "لطفا گروه انتظار را مشخص کنید." }}
            formClassName="w-2/5"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            htmlFor="indicators"
            aria-required
            className="m-1 block text-sm"
          >
            <span>عوامل ایجاد کننده رویداد</span>
            <span className="text-red-600 mr-1">*</span>
          </label>
          <Select
            onMenuOpen={handleClick}
            placeholder="..."
            isMulti
            required
            value={indicators}
            onChange={(selectedOptions) => setIndicators(selectedOptions)}
          />
        </div>
        <MacroGoalsExpectations
          control={control}
          onSelect={handleSelectedGoals}
          getValues={getValues}
        />
        <TextAreaController
          control={control}
          name="description"
          label="توضیحات انتظار و نیازمندی ذینفع"
        />
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2 mt-5">
          <Button size="sm" type="submit">
            ثبت انتظار
          </Button>
          {/* <Button
            type="button"
            size="sm"
            color="danger"
            onClick={handleModalClose}
          >
            انصراف
          </Button> */}
        </div>
      </form>
      {openModal && (
        <ChooseIndicatorsModal
          onClose={handleClose}
          onSelect={handleChangeIndicators}
          data={indicators}
        />
      )}
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default StakeholdersExpectationsModal;
```